# Как при помощи планировщика `apscheduler` сделать паузу в выполнении программы?

Tags: python, apscheduler

Как при помощи планировщика `apscheduler` сделать паузу в выполнении программы, подобную `time.sleep`, но до точного времени?

Comment: Зачем? Если вам нужна точность - `time.sleep` подойдёт лучше.Или вам нужно приостановить выполнение программы, пока на часах не будет, допустим, 12:00, независимо от текущего времени?

Comment: да, т.к. не могу всегда точно time.sleep просчитывать

Comment: Нужно действие выполнить один раз или каждый день, в те же 12:00? Можно не каждый день, а в определённые дни

Comment: Один раз, я не нашел такой функции, в add_job() необходимо всегда передавать функцию, которая выполнится в нужное время, а мне именно приостановка выполнения кода нужна, надеюсь объяснил

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё же использовать `time.sleep`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re

def SleepToTime(n):
    if re.match(r"[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\s(([0-1]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2}$)", n) is None:
        print("Дата или время в неправильном формате. Используйте YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Например, 2020-06-21 20:00:05")
        return

    TimeToSleep = (datetime.strptime(n,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.now()).total_seconds()

    if TimeToSleep < 0:
        print("Это время прошло", int(abs(TimeToSleep)), "секунд назад")
        return 
    time.sleep(int(TimeToSleep))
    print("Задержка завершена")


SleepToTime('2020-08-09 19:25:00')
```

Эта функция принимает строку с датой в формате "ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС", например,

`2020-06-22 10:18:00`. Нужно именно в таком формате. Если вы напишете не 00, а просто 0 или не 05, а просто 5, то это не пройдёт проверку.

Передаваемая строка проверяться регулярным выражением,  потом находится разница между текущим временем и передаваемым и проверяется, не прошло ли это время. Ну и выполняться задержка на указанное время. **Этот способ не работает при требуемой задержке более 2 (или немного больше) месяцев.** Это ограничение `time.sleep` в Python.

Также есть вариант без регулярных выражений:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def SleepToTime(n):
    try:
        TimeToSleep = (datetime.strptime(n,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    except ValueError:
        print("Дата или время в неправильном формате. Используйте YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Например, 2020-06-21 20:00:05")
        return

    if TimeToSleep < 0:
        print("Это время прошло", int(abs(TimeToSleep)), "секунд назад")
        return 
    time.sleep(int(TimeToSleep))
    print("Задержка завершена")


SleepToTime('2020-08-09 19:25:00')
```

В таком случае можно писать, например `2020-06-22 10:5:0`, не обязательно 05 и 00.

---

Если вы хотите всё же использовать `apScheduler`, то можно использовать `BlockingScheduler`.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

def function(text):
    print(text)
    scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)


scheduler.add_job(function, 'date', run_date=('2020-06-21 19:54:55'), args=['text'])

scheduler.start()
```

Эта функция вызовется всего один раз в момент наступления даты. Но `scheduler` всё равно продолжит блокировать процесс. Тут у вас есть 2 варианта:

1. Писать код, который должен выполниться после задержки прямо в этой функции (вызываемой `scheduler'ом`).
2. Сделать `scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)` и тогда блокировка завершится и код продолжит выполнение после `scheduler'а`.

Тут можно позволить задержку побольше. Я поставил 1000 лет и ошибок не было, возможно, он справится.

Comment: Большое спасибо, жаль не хватает голосов поставить вам лайк

Comment: А возможно ли scheduler использовать в linux чтобы он уже при старте ОС работал, а я мог добавлять в планировщик задания?

Comment: @АлексейТихонов для таких случаем специально для Linux есть системный планировщик `Cron`. Вы можете использовать его без `python` (например, для запуска тех же `python` скриптов), и в самом `apscheduler` есть возможность работать с `Cron`. Вот статья о настройке `Cron` https://losst.ru/nastrojka-cron И документация по `apscheduler`, где есть примеры с `Cron` - https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html